# iOS: Pre-populate field with user's first name

Tags: ios, ios5

I have a field for a user to enter a name into and I think it would be a nicer user experience if it was already pre-populated with their first name.

Is there a way in iOS 5 for an application to get the first name (or a nickname) of the device's user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't exactly what you're looking for but you can use:

```
NSString *deviceName = [[UIDevice currentDevice] name];
```

This will return the device name, eg. "John's iPhone" (of course it will only say this if the user decided to name his device this way).  I would not recommend using this in your form as the results can vary and frankly it won't make sense as a username, but it's something you might consider anyways.

If you're trying to get the user's Apple ID however then I'm pretty sure this isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

No. And I find it quite surprising that you are asking this, I mean, has iOS ever asked you to create a user account? No? How should it know who you are?

Comment: I sort of expected this, I just thought there might have been a way to get the the name of someone from their Apple account.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Address Book framework to present a modal view controller that lets you pick a person from the Contacts application.

I think you could also specify which group to show, but I don't know if the user is in a special group that shows just his or her contact information.

See the [Address Book Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH1-SW1).